# Selenium (firefox) hangs on WebElement.Click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox

## Problem

I've noticed through trial and error that my click function `click` (code below) hangs in firefox in a specific case. What happens is that I issue a login by clicking a login button, then try to click the profile button right after which hangs the execution.

My understanding of the issue is that `WebElement.click()` is a stalling function and for some reason it doesn't get resolved. My solution right now is to issue a `WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` call instead. It works, but I would like to know how I can resolve this issue since `sendKeys` doesn't work for all cases. So far this only happens in firefox, I don't have this issue in chrome.

`driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout` doesn't seem to make any difference.

If I `Thread.sleep` between the two click calls then it also works.

**Execution**

```
SeleniumCommands.click(driver, loginButton);
SeleniumCommands.click(driver, profilePage);
```

**Expected result**

login and go to the profile page.

**Actual result**

login and selenium get stuck on the second `driver.findElement(locator).click();` call.

**Workaround**

```
SeleniumCommands.click(driver, loginButton);
SeleniumCommands.click2(driver, profilePage);
```

**Code**

```
public static Boolean click(WebDriver driver, By locator, Integer... timeout) {

    try {
        waitFor(driver, ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator), (timeout.length > 0 ? timeout[0] : null));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException exception) {
        return false;
    }

    // this sometimes hangs in firefox
    driver.findElement(locator).click();

    return true;
}
```

```
public static Boolean click2(WebDriver driver, By locator, Integer... timeout) {

    try {
        waitFor(driver, ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator), (timeout.length > 0 ? timeout[0] : null));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException exception) {
        return false;
    }

    // This doesn't hang on firefox, but it can't always be used
    driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could U provide html with part that not work ??? Are You sure You got best possible locator from login button element ??? Are You waiting after page is loaded. Do you use implicit wait ???

Comment: I'm fairly certain there shouldn't be anything wrong with the locator for the login button. If I add a `Thread.sleep` between the two calls it works. 

Also, if I count elements found for the second click it finds the element, it just hangs when I try to click it.

Comment: Did You tried implicit wait with firefox driver ???

Comment: Yes. I've tried all 4 combinations of with and without `pageLoadTimeout` and `implicitlyWait`. I've heard you shouldn't mix implicit and explicit wait though.

Comment: Try javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: @mk_ Thanks. This seem to be working fine.